# How do I get around the Java silent install showing a UAC prompt?

Tags: windows-installer, java

The Java runtime installer has a [silent](http://java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml) installation switch, `jre-6u27-windows-i586-s.exe /s`. However, when [UAC](http://java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml) is set to any of the "Notify me" options, the Java installer still shows a prompt!

[image]

**Is there any way around this except to turn off UAC?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, if it were possible (easy) to install software bypassing UAC, then there would be no point in having UAC.  The whole idea behind UAC is to prevent unauthorized (read potentially dangerous) software from being installed.

If you use some of sort of network management software/service like SCCM, then that might be able to do it by having it's own software installation service installed.

Comment: Several other Windows Installers (MSI) that I run silently avoid the UAC prompt.

Comment: If the original installer has elevated permissions, and then install additional components inside of the _same_ process, this works.  However, if the installer launches a **different** installation process, then there is nothing you can do; save for rewriting the installer.

Comment: My "installer" is a PowerShell script that calls a bunch of other installers, copies files, etc.

Comment: Oh yeah, they probably don't invoke admin privileges or something.

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploying this to all your workstations?  If so you could set it to run under the local admin account which bypasses UAC as it's setup to run everything in admin mode by default (unless you've changed this via GPO).

Comment: Hm... I am running this as part of a complicated software deployment to a medical instrument. It is running a full Windows installation and has a builtin admin. However, we're running as a service account. I can look into this.